# How to perform click for this date picker, All have same ID, index value in UIautomatorviewer

Tags: appium

How to find element for date picker in appium, all the buttons have same resource ID and index as well(Some sample code will help, i have tried few but in those case index value were different in date picker). Even im not sure how to find xpath for these, is there a tool or something for finding xpath in appium ?

http://tinypic.com/r/34gstvd/8

Answer (score 0):

Refer to each NumberPicker field and after you can interact with it (sendKeys, clear etc.).

```
By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']//android.widget.EditText")
By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='1']//android.widget.EditText")
By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='2']//android.widget.EditText")
```